# What does the "model" field represent in the file /proc/cpuinfo?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

The following is the content of my /proc/cpuinfo file for a single core:

> processor : 0
>
> vendor_id : GenuineIntel
>
> cpu family    : 6
>
> model     : 42
>
> model name    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz
>
> stepping  : 7
>
> microcode : 0x1a
>
> cpu MHz       : 1600.000
>
> cache size    : 3072 KB
>
> physical id   : 0
>
> siblings  : 4
>
> core id       : 0
>
> cpu cores : 2
>
> apicid        : 0
>
> initial apicid    : 0
>
> fpu       : yes
>
> fpu_exception : yes
>
> cpuid level   : 13
>
> wp        : yes
>
> flags     : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
>
> bogomips  : 6185.67
>
> clflush size  : 64
>
> cache_alignment   : 64
>
> address sizes : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
>
> power management:

Can anyone please help, what does the "model" field represent. What does that "42" imply?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the model is a numbering system to describe the CPU generation and series. family 6/ model 42 (0x2A) is a 32 nanometer sandy bridge architecture.  See https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-and-processor-identification-with-cpuid-model-and-family-numbers

Comment: This link does not lead to fruitful information anymore, apparently. It leads to a list of pdf's about the architectures and development. This information may be in one of them, but the first in the list is a nrealy 5k page pdf that is, practically-speaking, very difficult to search